# I can't add liquidity from a router : Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

Tags: blockchain, solidity, hardhat, erc20, uniswap

I tried to just copy-paste the UniswapV2 factory and UniswapV2 Router in order to learn how everything work but I have a problem : when I try to addLiquidity with 2 tokens, I can't...

The error is : Transaction has been reverted by the EVM.

The factory contract : https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x952C4F94A3887914dE1024e9a2dc7BF2791313f9#code

The router contract : https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x9576c73e58C1Dad8A23Eb8554d0e835245c67b25#code

I don't understand why it doesn't work, because it's the same contract, maybe I missed something ?

I managed to add liquidity with the (real) UniswapV2Router, this is the tx : https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xb1f9f541cad4c2631be214d25c1005fbac8e163075764d98021a7c5f4ab52f66

And this is the tx where I have the error : https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x4f23b915a7bf26ae0db1c1a9c7fb957348c3aab38a1531f99fbbbe1777337a26

There is a picture of the error on MetaMask :

[Transaction has been reverted by the EEVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF3Ng.jpg)

Thank you for your time, have a good day !